# Why is the length of the same movie different?

Tags: dvd, matroska, blu-ray

Currently I am digitizing my collection of DVDs. Some of the DVDs have a scratch and cannot be read perfectly. When this occurs I am downloading this DVD from the internet and try to recover the dubbed audio tracks or subs from the disk and add them to the MKV format.

For some DVD however this is not necessarily easy. The reason? The DVD has a length of eg. 2h20. The downloaded one takes 6 minutes more.

Investigation led me to the fact that one of the sources is simply faster and slowing down the source to the same length from the other source leads to a perfectly usable MKV-file.

What could be the reason of this difference? Could this be a signature from the uploader or is this simply something with my player?

I do have to mention that all my DVDs are european DVDs and according to the 23,976 framerate the downloaded ones are american ones. Also possibly important: DVDs all have SD resolution (576p) and I download them in HD (1080p) if possible.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That would desyncronise the sources which is not the case. I just checked one of the movies. The downloaded one (video and dutch subtitles) is 1:33:31 and the dvd (dutch dubbed audio) is 2:27:12. The audio and subtitles are perfectly in sync when combined where the video and subtitles were slowed down by a factor of 0,958853545

Comment: "I do have to mention that all my dvd are european dvds and according to the 23,976 framerate the downloaded ones are american ones." - I'm not 100% certain if it applies in this case, but PAL and SECAM are 25 FPS. So that could certainly explain the time difference, etc.

Comment: @Anaksunaman This was my first thought as well but I wanted to be sure. It seems weird to me. Why has an American movie to be lenghtier and slower than a european one?  For most of the DVDs I had the same characteristics a slower downloaded once (all at 23.976 FPS) and as faster DVD (25 FPS)

Comment: Meanwhile I also did a quick check an seems this could has a good chance of being something. The DVD (25FPS) has 7953 sec times 25 FPS is 198 825 frames. The downloaded one: 8294 sec x 23,976 FPS = 198 856.944 frames. Makes 31.944 frames (1.2 sec @ 25 FPS) left which could be some dead space from the DVD